# react import function to handle input change instead of write again and again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state, dom-events

When we decided to use a form, we make some inputs and write a function to handle input changes. it means we will do it for every page that write a handle function again and again and again.

My question is that is it possible make a function for handle input changes to reusable like component ? If we want a form we use this function instead of write a handle change input function and we will not write it again and again.

I try to make but not. I didn't find any source about it.

Please help me

Comment: It depends on what action you are doing in that handler

Comment: You can create that Input field as a reusable component and import it wherever you want. Check the link and look at the react-select component. You will get some idea how you can build the common reusable component for a form element. https://reactjs.org/community/ui-components.html

Comment: in example on the link handleChange used localize in select component so that is the same thing as i say write handleChange again and again in every component but i want declare it only one time and use it whereever i want . ok ? link example is not what i want.